# Change IP phone settings programmatically

Tags: settings, voip

IP phones like [NRP1000](http://www.newrocktech.com/show/537.html) or [NRP1002](http://www.newrocktech.com/show/689.html) have a *browser-based setting interface* by which you can change all the phone settings. I was looking for some API or so, to do the same operation **programmatically**, but I could not find any document on this.

*A hard way I think is to emulate all the http/TCP communications*.

Any simpler suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Most VoIP phones support (auto)provisioning, usually few different methods of fetching configuration - pre-configured address, address based on manufacturer server, address from DHCP server, SIP multicast with ua-profile. Provisioning can be time-based (e.g. daily) and/or at phone reboot (which may be forced with SIP NOTIFY).

Refer to manufacturer documentation, perhaps contact manufacturer directly (I never heard of this brand but datasheet claims it supports provisioning). If something is missing look also at Fanvil documentation as first of these phones look definitively like one of Fanvil models.